Tax on Company Stock held in 401(k) plan when doing a Roth Conversion
I recently changed employers and I want to do remove some funds from the old employer's 401(k) plan and transfer it into a Roth IRA account with Fidelity that I also just opened. The thing is a portion of the funds in the 401(k) plan are held in company stock (~ 7%). Also the stocks have greatly depreciated in value i.e. its current market value is at least 25k lower than the cost basis.
I have learned that I can do a partial withdrawal and say, for example, if I did a conversion of $30,000 into a Roth IRA, then the amount will be withdrawn pro-rated i.e. 7% of the 30k will come from the company stock. I wanted to understand what the tax implication is of this Roth conversion; I know I owe taxes on the money withdrawn this year as income tax, but what about the portion of the money that came from the company stock? Is the whole 30k taxed as income tax or is the portion that came from company stock taxed differently (taxed on its original cost-basis even though the market value is significantly lower)?
By the way, the 30k ends up in my Roth IRA as cash (not an in-kind transfer of the stock portion that was withdrawn).
In my research so far, I'm inclined to think the whole 30k including the portion that came from stock will be taxed simply as income tax. This is because the amount transferred is equivalent to liquidated and transferred as cash. Is this correct?
Thanks!


how do you even have company stock in 401k, did you actually buy it? b) it doesn't matter which stock you have there, the treatment is the same.


the company matched my 401(k) contributions through stock. What is the treatment?

the company matched my 401(k) contributions through stock - Was it named "Enron" by chance? It's a huge red flag, just saying.

Before Enron that was normal. In the two companies  I worked for before Enron collapsed the match had to be done in stock, and you couldn't sell until you were near retirement age.  The company stock could be treated according to the  net unrealized appreciation rules, if it goes into a taxable account.

The entire $30k converted from your Traditional 401k to your Roth IRA would be taxable as income, regardless of whether it was originally your company's stock, cash, or other investments. You also don't have to pro-rate the conversion across your 401k investments, although generally things will be sold based on your target investment allocation. From a tax perspective here (with only pre-tax money being converted), it doesn't matter.
Net unrealized appreciation (NUA) treatment of company stock (when meeting all eligibility requirements) would allow only the cost basis of your company's stock to be taxable as ordinary income (any appreciation on top of that would be capital gain), but that requires you to distribute the company stock (i.e. get it out of tax-advantaged vehicles), not convert it to a Roth IRA. Therefore, NUA wouldn't apply here.

Say if the stocks' cost basis was 20k and current market value is 5k. If I distribute the stock as an in-kind transfer to a brokerage account so I don't lose my position in the stock, will I be taxable on the original cost basis of 20k? (i.e. even if the market value has depreciated?) Also what happens if I sold the stock later at a deficit i.e. less than the cost basis? Can I claim losses on that commodity, having already paid taxes on the higher cost basis and I never broke even..

@NeedToKnow I've never heard of anyone approaching NUA treatment with stock at a loss, but yes, following NUA tax rules that appears to be correct. There may be differences for loss shares I'm not aware of (NUA really is for low basis, highly appreciated stock), but it probably would be no better than a standard taxable distribution.  Also don't forget the 10% early withdrawal penalty if you are younger than 59.5 or don't meet any other penalty exception.

You can only transfer cash, or specified assets in kind (if both parties support that). Taxes will be calculated based on the closing price of the specified assets on the transfer day. There is no unclearness once you picked the assets for the transfer.
Btw, it is a good idea to transfer them while they are lower valued -> lower value = less taxes, and when they recover, it's tax free gains in the Roth IRA.
